# What is the right combination of spacers for a 10 speed cassette on a Mavic HG freehub?

Tags: cassette, freehub

In general, for 11-speed HG hubs one uses a 1.85 mm spacers for 8-10 speed cassettes and some 10-speed road cassettes  use one extra 1 mm spacer always.

However, I am confused about Mavic hubs. According to https://www.slowtwitch.com/Tech/Cassette_How-To_-_Part_2_3257.html they used to be wider (by 1.75 mm) even before the Shimano 11 speed freehubs and so they were already compatible with 11 speed and a 1.75 mm spacer was used for 8-10 speed cassettes). However, that is a 2012 article.

When buying a current Mavic wheel with an HG freehub that does not come with any spacer, which combination of spacers should one use for 10 speed cassettes? The Mavic web site for the [Allroad Disc](https://www.mavic.com/en-us/p/allroad-disc-rr0994?variant=137) wheel says just

> Freewheel technology: Instant Drive 360
> Freewheel: Shimano HG road

and I was not able to find any documentation mentioning any spacers whatsoever.

Comment: BTW shopping for "a spacer between a cassette and a freehub" proved to be a royal pain so far in ordinary bike shops. They do hot have it in the shops. The bike repair guys likely have it but the shop guys can't access it. Maybe I just came too early and too late so that only the shop guys where present.

Comment: The easiest way I found is to just look for "spacer" and then filter by brand (Shimano).

Comment: I wasn't able to find able manuals on the Mavic site...

Comment: https://technicalmanual.mavic.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1.75mm spacer is only for `FTS-L` hubs. ID360 Mavic hubs have standard Shimano HG road 11 splines, so you can use a standard 1.85mm spacer for a HG 10-speed MTB cassette, and the additional 1mm spacer for the 10 speed road cassettes that require it.

Note that [this page from the technical doc](https://technicalmanual.mavic.com/tech-mavic/technical_manual/data/mavic_tech.php?display=product&family=1039&subfamily=1194&macronu=29672) lists the freehub bodies as `HG11 Freewheel Body ID360`.

Anecdotal evidence: my "fun" bike has a 10 speed MTB cassette, and I have two pairs of Allroad wheels ("basic" and S) and I can alternate between the wheels and the trainer (that has a standard HG road, also with a spacer) without needing any adjustment.

Comment: Damn, so I ordered probably the wrong one (the description was not completely clear saying 1.8 mm Shimano made by Mavic). At least it was not that expensive.  Wait, MTB cassettes do not need the 1 mm spacer? But they use the same sprocket spacing as the road ones.

Comment: I became really confused. Originally I was just shopping for the 1.85 mm spacer in physical shops around, but unsuccessfully. Only later I realized that Mavic used to have this specialty. I ordered that one online because the local shops' staff were unable to sell me anything.

Comment: If you want to avoid confusion with Mavic, ignore articles older than 2018, and the ones that do not mention ID360. There was really a turn in the approach with ID360 in term of design. But yes, this 1.85mm is hard to find as it's very rare to mount "pure" MTB cassettes on road freehub bodies, and it's shipped with the road cassettes that require it (11-speed with largest sprocket larger or equal to 34T) or is provided with trainers.

Comment: But in gravel you do need it for 10 speed gravel cassettes like the CS-HG500-10 that comes with the GRX400 groupset, no?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Looks like one of the "edge cases" that may be worth a separate question, if it has not been already asked. Bike-components.de says that the 1mm spacer is only required for 10-speed road cassettes with aluminium spider, but I don't know if it applies to this cassette. The 1.85mm one is required for all 10-speed cassettes (in addition to the 1mm one, if applicable).

Comment: I do not think you need the 1 mm one, it is an MTB/road cassette (Deore/Tiagra) although the first sentence of my question shows that I became confused about this one this morning as well.. But the 1.85 mm for sure.